# What is typographically right: 100€ or 100 €?

Tags: typography

I'm wondering if there is supposed to be a white space between the number and the € sign.

`100€` or `100 €`

Comment: This is a grammar/language-specific question, not a typographic question — which @e100's answer proves: `€100` would be plain wrong in e.g. Finnish where `100 €` is correct. (`100€` would be as incorrect too, because it should be said `hundred euros` not `hundredeuros`.)

Comment: I think you're right, but that doesn't make the question wrong. I'll amend my answer with a heavy caveat.

Answer (score 4):

As per Koiyu's comment, this is language/locale specific.

But assuming UK/US English, it's either:

- €100
- one hundred Euro(s)
- 100 Euro
- 100 EUR [ISO currency code]

I believe in French or German there'd be a space after a currency symbol:

- € 100

Comment: In french, the currency is located after the number: 100 €